# Camel unit testing is failing always, I can't explain myself why the expected is 0 or how to assert the expected correctly

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have this rest endpoint with Apache Camel to lookup after some values from different sources, first I validate the request then based on path I go to different routes:

```java
restConfiguration()
    .component("servlet")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
...

rest("/lookup/{path}")
    .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .post().type(LookupRequest.class).outType(LookupResponse.class)
    .to("direct:validate-request")

from("direct:validate-request")
    .routeId(Constants.ROUTE_VALIDATE_REQUEST)
    .to("bean-validator://x")
    .process(exchange ->
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("lookupType", env.getProperty("lookup.path." + exchange.getIn().getHeader("path", String.class)))
    )
    .to("bean:lookupValidationService?method=validate(${body}, ${header.lookupType})")
    .toD("direct:db-lookup-${header.lookupType}");

from("direct:db-lookup-customer")
    .routeId(Constants.ROUTE_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP)
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, CamelRouter.CAMEL_BODY)
        ...
    .to("sql:{{lookup.queries.customer}}?placeholder=~&usePlaceholder=true")
    .process(new SqlQueryResultProcessor())
        ...
    .endRest();
```

this is one of my attempts to test the route:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = LookupServiceApplication.class)
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("log:.*")
@UseAdviceWith
class CameltestingApplicationTests {

    @Autowired CamelContext camelContext;
    @Autowired ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @EndpointInject("mock:direct:db-lookup-customer")
    MockEndpoint customerMock;

    static List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>() {{
        add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("customerName", "Test customer");
        }});
    }};

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() throws Exception {
        camelContext.setTracing(true);
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(camelContext, Constants.ROUTE_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP, routeBuilder -> {
            routeBuilder.interceptSendToEndpoint("sql:*").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().process(e -> e.getIn().setBody(results));
        });
    }
    @Test
    public void testReceive() throws Exception {
        camelContext.start();
        // Expect:
        customerMock.expectedMessageCount(1);
        // And: the process to set the header
        customerMock.expectedHeaderReceived("lookupType", "customer.info");

        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("path", "customer.info");
        Map<String, Object> keywords = new HashMap<>();
        keywords.put("customerNumber", 1234678);
        LookupRequest request = new LookupRequest();
        request.setKeywords(keywords);

        // When we send the message
        producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders("direct:validate-request", request, headers);
        // Everything is satisfied.
        Assert.assertNotNull(camelContext.hasEndpoint("direct:db-lookup-customer"));
        customerMock.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

this is the log:

```
2021-07-12 12:10:13.604  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Apache Camel 3.11.0 (Lookup service) started in 1s246ms (build:160ms init:1s7ms start:79ms)
2021-07-12 12:10:13.623  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            : *--> [validate    ] [from[direct:validate-request]    ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.624  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [validate    ] [bean-validator://x               ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.727  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [validate    ] [Processor@0x166ddfb7             ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.728  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [validate    ] [bean:lookupValidationService?meth] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.733  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [validate    ] [direct:db-lookup-${header.lookupT] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.739  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            : ---> [customer    ] [from[direct:db-lookup-customer]  ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.740  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [customer    ] [log                              ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.740  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [customer    ] [setHeader[customerNumber]        ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.891  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [customer    ] [sql:{{lookup.queries.customer}}?p] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.892  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [customer    ] [Processor@0x1feb586d             ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupRequest, Body: LookupRequest(keywords={customerNumber=1234678})]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.895  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [customer    ] [Processor@0x34695b23             ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: null, Body: [{customerName=Test customer}]]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.896  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            :      [customer    ] [log                              ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupResponse, Body: LookupResponse(ok=true, errorMessage=null, results=[{customerName=Test customer}])]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.896  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            : <--- [customer    ] [from[direct://db-lookup-customer]] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupResponse, Body: LookupResponse(ok=true, errorMessage=null, results=[{customerName=Test customer}])]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.897  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.Tracing                            : *<-- [validate    ] [from[direct://validate-request]  ] Exchange[Id: 32F8D8FB9A7CF84-0000000000000000, BodyType: com.odfl.freight.lookupservice.model.LookupResponse, Body: LookupResponse(ok=true, errorMessage=null, results=[{customerName=Test customer}])]
2021-07-12 12:10:13.900  INFO 660 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.m.MockEndpoint                   : Asserting: mock://direct:db-lookup-customer is satisfied

...

java.lang.AssertionError: mock://direct:db-lookup-customer Received message count 0, expected at least 1

    at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.fail(MockEndpoint.java:1790)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.assertTrue(MockEndpoint.java:1773)
```

I'm new with testing Apache Camel routes can somebody please help me to understand where is the problem or how to validate the output as you can see the exchange object body is there and passed. I already tried a few things to mock this endpoint but nothing seems to work and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I cannot see whether your test fails or not, may be incomplete logs?

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: mock://direct:db-lookup-customer Received message count 0, expected at least 1

Answer (score 0):

You've mocked only `log` endpoints with your `@MockEndpointsAndSkip("log:.*")` and you are injecting `customerMock` as `mock:direct:db-lookup-customer`, but if it's not in the route how can it receive a message?
I think all you need is to mock your `direct:db-lookup-customer` in some way, e.g. within `adviceWith` or with an annotation